# how to apply lm() to datasets split by factors

Tags: r, apply

In a housing dataset, there are three variables, which are bsqft (the building size of the house), county(a factor variable with 9 levels) and price. I would like to fit an individual regression line using bsqft and price for each separate county. Instead of calling lm() function repeatedly, I prefer using apply function in r but have no idea to create it. Could anyone help me with that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe look at lmList in the lme4 package after first using split().

Comment: @joran, split isn't necessary: `lmList(price~bsqft | county, data=...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` and `broom` to do regressions by group and summarise the information back into a dataframe

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

your_dataset %>% 
  group_by(county) %>% 
  do(tidy(lm(price ~ bsqft, data=.)))
```